# How to get value from class Car to class Order

Tags: python, django

I'm need to get "Make" from class Car to "Make" in Order Class:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    Make = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True) #that i need to get in Order class
    Model = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Make) + " " + str(self.Model)


class Order(models.Model):

    #make = Car.Make - like that, but it is not work
    #make1 = models.ForeignKey(Car.Make, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # it doesn't work either

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # that's work but it's give me return of __str__


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Order_amount) + " " + str(self.Order_status)
```

P.S. I just started to learn django, and I can not find any information about it

Comment: What do you mean by 'get it in Order class'? That's unclear.

Comment: You obtain this with `self.car.Make`.

Comment: I have a website that displays the name of the machine attached to the order. And I need to get separately the name of the machine and its brand, which would be displayed in different lines

Comment: "You obtain this with self.car.Make." - no it's telling me undefinied variable self

Comment: @Jackyyy: of course in a *method* of `Order`. But it looks like you use `self` somewhere else. Please do not include `Make` in an `Order` as well, since that introduces *data duplication*.

Answer (score 0):

learn about "Foreignkey"

use Foreignkey is correct

a=Order.objects.get(???=???)

print(a.car.Make)